# How to put login and registration form on same index page

Tags: django, registration

As of now, I have my registration form and my log in form on two different pages, I can't seem to put them in one view because the way I did it, the views require different return statements. So here is my registration view function:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()

    return render_to_response('register.html', args)

def register_success(request):
         return render_to_response('register_success.html')
```

and here is my log in and authentication view:

```
def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login.html', c)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')
```

Here is the template for the log in page:

```
            <form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                <label for="username">User name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">

                <input type="submit" value="login" />

            </form>
```

and here is the template for the registration page:

```
<h2>Register</h2>
<form action="/accounts/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}

<input type="submit" value="Register" />

</form>
```

Again, I can't seem to put them together because the views have to return different things.. any idea on how to do it?

EDIT: This is my urls.py:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', index),
url(r'^accounts/auth/$', auth_view),
url(r'^invalid/$', invalid_login),
url(r'^accounts/register/$', register_user),
url(r'^accounts/register_success/$', register_success),
```

so it will only use the register_user view if the url is accounts/register, I want it to user the register_view view if it is the homepage (^$). My index view is this:

```
def index(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('index.html', c)
```

it basically just adds a csrf token to my index.html (log in template, as seen above). This is why I want to be able to somehow merge index and the register_user view, since register_user view calls the actual form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST) which is used in the registration template (the registration template uses {{form}}

Comment: I think this makes for a nice separation when it comes to the views. I wouldn't change it.

Comment: Any reason why you would want it in the same view?

Comment: Okay I edited my post, can you read the EDIT section again? I kind of changed which two views I want put together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to show login and registration on the same page. Create a html page with two forms. Action of one of them to url `'/accounts/register/'` and another one to `'/accounts/auth/'`.

for example, change your register.html to:

```
<html>
    <head><body>
        <form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <label for="username">User name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">

            <input type="submit" value="login" />

        </form>
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <form action="/accounts/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{form}}

            <input type="submit" value="Register" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When submit the form, it will go to corresponding view and redirect based on that view.

EDIT:To pass a `MyRegistrationForm` instance you can update the index `view` as follows:

```
def index(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    c.update({'form':MyRegistrationForm()})
    return render_to_response('index.html', c)
```

use the login.html as above html code in the answer.

Comment: Okay I edited my post, can you read the EDIT section again? I kind of changed which two views I want put together.

Comment: You can pass a MyRegistrationForm instance to indedx.html via the view  index. Please find my edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a help of little Javascript. Let's create a input field first:

```
<input type="hidden" name="button-name" id="button-name" value="" />

<input type="submit" name="register-button" id="register-button" onclick="changeValue()" />

function changeValue(){
   document.getElementById('button-name').value="register"
}
```

Now, in your **views** do this:

```
button_name = request.POST['button-name']

if button-name=='register':
    # Do the registration
    # Redirect to another view or template

else:
    # Do your login thing
    # Redirect where you want
```